# Logback-classic 1.2.8 DBAppender Missing

Tags: java, logback-classic

I'm trying to upgrade the logback-classic library from version 1.2.3 to 1.2.8. The patch notes say that all DB related code has been removed, so the main DBAppender class no longer exists in the new version https://logback.qos.ch/news.html. Has anyone found some kind of upgrade guide or know of a workaround solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Please see https://logback.qos.ch/news.html.

> 2022-04-20, Release of logback.db version 1.2.11.1
>
> As of logback version 1.2.8 DBAppender no longer ships with logback.
> However, DBAppender for logback-classic is available under the
> following Maven coordinates:
>
> ch.qos.logback.db:logback-classic-db:1.2.11.1
>
> and for logback-access under
>
> ch.qos.logback.db:logback-access-db:1.2.11.1
>
> Both of these artifacts require
> ch.qos.logback.db:logback-core-db:1.2.11.1 which will be pulled in
> automatically by Maven's transitivity rules.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing after upgrading spring to the 2.6.3 which pulls in logback version 1.2.8+ through spring-boot-starter-logging dependency.

According to logback's site: https://logback.qos.ch/news.html in version 1.2.8: "2) we have removed all database (JDBC) related code in the project with no replacement."

My logback xml configuration file has a custom DB Appender in it and the application failed to build with the following error:
`Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender`

After doing some research, I found a ticket in the logback backlog with a request to document how to proceed. https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1609

Apparently the DB appender was removed due to a vulnerability.

According to the developer: "The source code is still there. Until this issue is resolved, you can fetch the code from tag 1.2.8 and rebuild. The DBAppender issue is a bit more complex than what people think. As you can imagine, we have a lot on my plate these days but we'll get to it eventually."

So it sounds like the code was removed while they work on a fix and support will be added back eventually. I wouldn't count on a quick fix though.

As a workaround I have pinned the logback version in my projects gradle file so that I can use the latest version of spring along with the latest version of logback that still supports the DB appender class.

Here is the syntax I used:

```
ext['logback.version'] = '1.2.7'
```

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade SpringBoot from v 2.6.1 to 2.6.6. And try downgrade to 1.2.7 as you mention, it is works! for anyone using pom.xml, just put the dependency and override the newer version.
 <dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.7</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.7</version>
 </dependency>